# Why java.lang.StringEncoding.encode ignore given charset to use default one?

Tags: java, character-encoding

My app default encoding is set to "UTF-8" (using *-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8* on startup).
When I use the String class method "getBytes(String charsetName)" with charset="ISO-8859-1", it appears that *StringCoding.encode* finally uses the default charset (UTF-8) instead of the given one (ISO-8859-1).

For an unknown reason, I can debug step by step on this method, but I'm not able to inspect inner elements value (only parameters which are named arg0, arg1 ...)

In java 1.6.10, StringCoding.encode is written :

```
static byte[] encode(String charsetName, char[] ca, int off, int len)
    throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    StringEncoder se = (StringEncoder)deref(encoder);
    String csn = (charsetName == null) ? "ISO-8859-1" : charsetName;
    if ((se == null) || !(csn.equals(se.requestedCharsetName())
                  || csn.equals(se.charsetName()))) {
        se = null;
        try {
        Charset cs = lookupCharset(csn);
        if (cs != null)
            se = new StringEncoder(cs, csn);
        } catch (IllegalCharsetNameException x) {}
        if (se == null)
            throw new UnsupportedEncodingException (csn);
        set(encoder, se);
    }
    return se.encode(ca, off, len);
}
```

With step by step debug, I never enter the if block and then no new StringEncoder with my ISO-8859-1 charset is created. Finally, the Charset.defaultCharset() method is called.

Any clues ?
Thanks

Comment: Is the -Dfile.ecoding=UTF-8 actually spelt like that? If so it should be -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Comment: Could you post a complete example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) where this occurs?

Answer (score 3):

If you're not getting into the `if` block, then this expression must be false

```
(se == null) || !(csn.equals(se.requestedCharsetName())
                  || csn.equals(se.charsetName()))
```

That means that:

- `se` mustn't be null
- The second part must be `true` before hitting the `!`, so one of these subexpressions must be true:

  - `csn.equals(se.requestedCharsetName())`
  - `csn.equals(se.charsetName())`

In other words, `se` is already appropriate for the charset name you've requested.

This isn't using the "default" encoding for the VM; it's using the encoder last used in this thread.

I *highly* doubt you've found a JRE bug - it looks okay to me. So what caused you to debug into this to start with? Can you provide a short but complete program which demonstrates an *error* using this? Something encoding to the wrong bytes?

Comment: Of course it's not a jre bug, there must been something I haven't understand.

Comment: @Redmat: So do you have a short but complete program which demonstrates `String.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")` giving the wrong result?

Comment: I'm working on it :) Actually, with a very short program, I'm not able to reproduce the bug. I think that the line `StringEncoder se = (StringEncoder)deref(encoder);` is the key of my issue.

Comment: The reason why I get into this is because with my file-encoding set to UTF-8 for my application and my target charset - for the functionnality i have to code - det to ISO-8859-1, I obtain unreadable bytes when writing my result into a File. If I open this file with PSPad hex, a lot of byte are replaced by 0x3F, which correspound to '?' in ISO-8859-1

Comment: @Redmat: That suggests you've got characters in your string which aren't representable in ISO-8859-1, which is entirely feasible...

Comment: If I try to use UTF-8 charset for my functionnality, I obtain EFBFBD bytes instead. And If I change the file.encoding to ISO-8859-1, then it works perfectly (but I have to make it work with this property set to UTF-8)

Comment: @Redmat: It's not really clear what your program is doing, exactly. Are you ever reading files using the default encoding? Bytes EF BF BD represent U+FFFD, which is the replacement character used for characters which are unknown or unrepresentable in Unicode.

Comment: My program fills a ByteArrayOutputStream with bytes obtained from Strings. ISO-8859-1 must be the source and target charset. I just tried UTF-8 to see what happens when  my default encoding equals the target charset. It only works if my default JVM encoding is set to ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @Redmat: So where does it get those strings from in the first place? It sounds like you're using the default encoding *somewhere* that you shouldn't be...

Comment: That's what I think too, but I'm not abble to figure where.

Comment: @Redmat: At least you have a better idea of how the data is flowing through your app... we only have bits and pieces. If you could update your question with a more complete explanation of where the data comes from, how you're reading it etc, then it may be a lot clear. For example, if you're using `FileReader`, that will *always* use the default encoding.

Comment: That's what I think too, but I'm not abble to figure where. Input strings come from xml files. Into my ByteArrayOutputStram, I also write some byte[] which are obtained by the transformation of "hexa strings" to byte[]. By "hexa-string", I mean string representation of hexadecimal Byte ("5649534120454C" is transformed into byte[] {0x56, 0x49, 0x53, 0x41, 0x20, 0x45, 0x4C} for example)

Comment: Thank you for your help and time, I will investigate further more, and come back with more explaination

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the

`-Dfile.ecoding=UTF-8` 
to

`-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

encode should never ignore the given charset to revert to the one given in -Dfile.encoding.

It does. As does decode by the way, even if the source does show that it finds the charset, and sets it in the line:

```
set(encoder, se);
```

Neither encode or decode are threadsafe, so the value is bound to be overridden by the system default, it may be before or after decode manages to use the set value though.

Imho, this is a bug in the JRE. True the OP had a typo, but that does not change the fact that if you ask String to decode a byte array to UTF-8, it should always return UTF-8, and not silently fall back to something else.